# Flutter passing data from one screen to another as a stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, state-management

How can I pass data from one screen to another as a stream?

I have a screen showing list of products using Firebase Stream (StreamProvider) when I click on a product I want to go to anther screen where I can display the product details. I want to pass the list of products to the details page as stream so any changes I make on the details screen will automatically update the firestore document.

```
    onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ProductDetails(
                                products: products
                              )));
                },
```

On the product details screen I can only get the products as `List<Product>` instead of `Stream<List<Product>>`

Comment: why you need to pass it.
you can use that stream to the `streamBuilder` and access the `snapshot.data`

Comment: I'm navigating to different screen so I don't know how to access the stream.

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter the way to send data to a new screen is described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data).

However, I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203763/passing-firebase-cloud-messaging-data-to-n-screens-above-the-current-screen-and) which might seem helpful for your use-case.

You may try BLoC implementation here. Furthermore, I came across [this Medium article](https://medium.com/flutterpub/when-firebase-meets-bloc-pattern-fb5c405597e0) that might shed some light on this issue.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks for that. I think BLoC might be the solution for my problem and I'm looking into it.