# Get MaterialPageRoute from Firestore - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, materialpageroute

I don't know whether it's possible or not but I want to get the new page for my navigator from the firestore database. Let me explain:

I have the following code:

```
onTap: () {
   Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) => Example()));
                      },
```

I don't want to have a fixed page here like "Example()".
I want to get the information on which page I have to use somewhere from my database. Is that possible? Thanks for your answers. You're great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Flutter, the way to send data to a new screen is described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data).
- A simple use case of flutter navigation using MaterialPageRouter is
  listed [here](https://grokonez.com/flutter/flutter-navigator-example-navigation-send-return-data-to-from-new-screen).
- However, I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52206100/15803365) which might seem useful for your
  use-case.
- You may try BLoC implementation here. Furthermore, I came across this
  [BLoC article](https://medium.com/flutterpub/when-firebase-meets-bloc-pattern-fb5c405597e0) that might shed some light on this issue.